# Show a HTML dialoge with Twig and Silex using template inheritence

Tags: php, model-view-controller, dialog, twig, silex

I'm using Silex with Twig and want to show a (HTML-only, no JS) dialog/alert-div/form to the user after an action was selected. This dialog should be shown on the same page the action was initiated on and might contain forms created with the Symfony `Forms` Library.

For that i figured, that the dialog should be a `{% block %}` on the template of the original page. In order to show that page i also need all the information that the original controller generates.

I found 3 different ways on how to achieve that, but all of them feel *wrong* and not very extensible:

### 1. Additional optional URL-Parameter. Exchange template in Controller:

```
$app->match('/someURL/{action}', [...])
                ->assert('action', '(|delete)')
                ->value('action', '');
/*[...]*/
function someURL(Application $app, Request $request, $action) {
    /*[...]*/
    $template = 'someURL.twig';
    $targs = ['a' => 'b'];
    if ($action === 'delete') {
        /*[...] Create Form, handle form action...*/
        $template = 'someURL_delete.twig';
        $targs['form'] = $form->createView();
    }
    return $app->render($template, $targs);
}
```

`someURL.twig`:

```
{% block content %}
    {% block confirmationDialog %}
    {% endblock confirmationDialog %}
    {# [...] #}
{% endblock %}
```

`someURL_delete.twig`:

```
{% extends 'someURL.twig' %}

{% block confirmationDialog %}
    {{ form(form) }}
{% endblock confirmationDialog %}
```

### 2. Additional Controller that calls default controller with argument

```
$app->match('/someURL/', [...]);
$app->match('/someURL/delete', [...]);
/*[...]*/
function someURL(Application $app, Request $request, $dialog = null) {
    /*[...]*/
    $template = empty($dialog) ? 'someURL.twig' : 'someURL_delete.twig';
    $targs = ['a' => 'b', 'form' => $dialog];
    return $app->render($template, $targs);
}

function someURL_delete(Application $app, Request $request) {
    /*[...] Create Form, handle form action...*/
    return someURL($app, $request, $form);
}
```

Templates identical to 1.

### 3. Controller that allows overwriting template and initial template args

```
$app->match('/someURL/', [...]);
$app->match('/someURL/delete', [...]);
/*[...]*/
function someURL(Application $app, Request $request, $template = 'someURL.twig', $targs = []) {
    /*[...]*/
    $targs += ['a' => 'b'];
    return $app->render($template, $targs);
}

function someURL_delete(Application $app, Request $request) {
    /*[...] Create Form, handle form action...*/
    return someURL($app, $request, 'someURL_delete.twig', ['form' => $form]);
}
```

Templates identical to 1.

The last option seems to be the most flexible one, but it feels like something one shouldn't do. Also i'm a little bit afraid about security (is there a way someone could overwrite these values maliciously?).

Is there a better option that i did not find or come up with?
Maybe one could also use the [HTTP Fragment](https://silex.symfony.com/doc/2.0/providers/http_fragment.html)-Feature in a smart way? I don't know.